# Cloning a Request with the already downloaded response

Tags: scrapy

From within a scrapers parse callback, I wish to clone a request along with its response object and change its callback.

The behavior I'm expecting is that will generate a request, and it will have its callback executed skipping the download step, since it already has the original response object.

Is it possible to put new requests into the queue without ending the current iteration in the callback.

Furthermore, is it possible to generate a new request object for other spiders within the crawler?

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
response.copy()
yield another_function(response)

def another_function(self, response):
   #here comes that your logic
```

request related data is available in `response.request`

Comment: See this is where I've hit the wall, this terminates the existing iteration in the parse callback. I should of clarified, that I still need the original iteration to complete. As yield ticks over iterator on parse. 
I'll have to edit my question, as I'm not wanting to yield, I want it shoved in job queue.